# SharePoint Designer: Email Workflow based on names in lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I am trying to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer where in List A it will email the people in Columns: OCR PM, BSC, Pri DBA, Sec DBA, and Tech Mgr only if someone updates/appends changes in the Column "Migration Update Notes".

However, Columns: OCR PM, BSC, Pri DBA, Sec DBA, Tech Mgr are lookup columns being pulled from another List B.

Is there anyway to achieve this with a workflow?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Look up values are set by the ID of the list item you are connecting to.  You will have to have something in your workflow, or some code behind, to create some case logic to state and set the email value in another variable based on the selected look up field value.

Pseudo Ex:

```
var emailVar //as String

if (lookUpVal == 2)  {
    emailVar = "email@email.com"
}
```

Then in your workflow, set the email To: value to emailVar.  Set your var as a string in your workflow, and then set it as email address in you workflow action.  You could even do this in a calculated field if you wanted to and use the calulated field data as the email.  There are a few ways to do this.  Hope this helps.